# Derivative of the determinant with respect to the vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, determinant, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

There is a vector $\boldsymbol{v}=[x, y, z]^T$ and a matrix $\boldsymbol{A}(x,y,z)$.

How is the derivative of a determinant of a matrix with respect to a vector calculated, i.e.:

$\frac{d|\boldsymbol{A}|}{d\boldsymbol{v}}=?$

Here are some calculations from Mathcad Prime. Here $A$ and $M$ are a matrix-function and a matrix of arbitrary numbers, and $v$ is a parameter vector. And $q$ is the function to be differentiated with respect to the vector $v$.

[image]

I differentiate the function $q$ with respect to each of the parameters $x,y,z$. I need to find a union operation that "packs" all in the function $f(trace(\cdot),\otimes,\partial_v A)$, I think, it probably includes the Kronecker product, tensor, etc. That's what I need to find if it exists.

**EDIT №2:**

[image]

Comment: Have a look at Jacobi's formula. The derivative of the determinant can be computed by taking the trace of a matrix product.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon Yes, I know about this formula. But it is written for the derivative with respect to a scalar. I'm wondering if it is possible to obtain a similar formula for the entire vector of parameters at once, along which the determinant is differentiated.

Comment: The formula holds also for the derivative with respect to a vector, as it gives you the differential of the function $A\mapsto\det A$ along the direction $\dot{A}$. I am on my phone now, I'll write down some more details later.

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon Ok, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\A{A^{-1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\dgrad#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\dgradLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$[Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Alternative_Derivation) for the determinant can be summarized as
$$\eqalign{
\a &= \det(A) \qiq \dgrad{\a}{t}= \a\trace{\A\dgradLR{A}{t}} \\
}$$
where $t$ is some scalar parameter.

Sequentially setting $t$ to the components of the $v$ vector
leads to the desired result
$$\large\eqalign{
\grad{\a}{v} &= \a \pmatrix{
\trace{\A \gradLR{A}{x}} \\
\trace{\A \gradLR{A}{y}} \\
\trace{\A \gradLR{A}{z}} \\
} \\\\
}$$

### Update

In response to the comments, let
$$\eqalign{
&a=\vc A,\quad b=\vc{A^{-T}} \\
&J=\grad{a}{v}\qquad\big\{{\rm Jacobian\:of\:}a\big\} \\
}$$
then employing Jacobi's formula in differential form yields
$$\eqalign{
d\a &= \a\;A^{-T}:dA \\
  &= \a\;b:da \\
  &= \a\;b:J\,dv \\
  &= \a\;J^Tb:dv \\
\grad{\a}{v} &= \a\;J^Tb \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
F:G &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n F_{ij}G_{ij} \;=\; \trace{F^TG} \\
G:G &= \|G\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\tt1)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
F:G &= G:F \\
F:G &= F^T:G^T \\
H:\LR{FG} &= \LR{HG^T}:F \\&= \LR{F^TH}:G \\
}$$
As with the Hadamard product, the matrix on each side of
the multiplication symbol $(:)$ must have exactly the same dimensions.

Comment: I'll rephrase the question. What operation (or set of operations) is needed for its result to be equivalent to the vector of traces that is presented in your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Jacobi's formula for the derivative of the determinant is usually stated as follows:

**Theorem.** For a path $t\mapsto A(t)$ of matrices, one has
\begin{equation}
\partial_t\det A(t)=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\mathrm{adj}(A(t))\,\dot{A}(t)\right).
\end{equation}

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#cite_ref-1) explains where this formula comes from. To use this result for your question, consider your parameter-dependent matrix as a matrix-valued function $A:\mathbb{R}^3\to M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$. The derivative $\partial_{v}A$ is the directional derivative of this function, so for any point $p\in\mathbb{R}^3$ we want to compute
\begin{equation}
\partial_v\det A(p)=\partial_t\Bigr|_{t=0}\det A(p+t\,v).
\end{equation}
Let $B(t)=A(p+t\,v)$ and we can apply Jacobi's formula to get
\begin{equation}
\partial_v\det A(p)=\partial_t\Bigr|_{t=0}\det B(t)=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\mathrm{adj}(B(0))\,\partial_t\Bigr|_{t=0}B(t)\right)=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\mathrm{adj}(A)\,\partial_vA\right)(p).
\end{equation}

A more geometric way to think about this: "$\det$" is a function from the set of $n$ by $n$ matrices to the complex (or real) numbers. Jacobi's formula is telling us what the differential of this function is, namely
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathrm{d}(\mathrm{det})_A:T_AM_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})&\to\mathbb{C}\\
\dot{A}&\mapsto\mathrm{Tr}\left(\mathrm{adj}(A)\,\dot{A}\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
What you want to compute is the differential of $\det$ composed with some function $A:\mathbb{R}^3\to M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$, and the differential of the composition is the composition of the differentials
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}\big((x,y,z)\mapsto\det A(x,y,z)\big)_p(v)=\mathrm{d}(\mathrm{det})_{A(p)}\left(\partial_vA\right)=\mathrm{Tr}\left(\mathrm{adj}(A)\,\partial_vA\right)(p).
\end{equation}

For example, assume that $A(x,y,z)$ is the simple matrix-valued function $$A(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix} x & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & y & 0\\ 0& 0 & z\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then the determinant is $\det A(x,y,z)= x y z$. Let's fix the vector $v=(a,b,c)$, then the derivative of the determinant is $\partial_v\left(\det A(x,y,z)\right)=ayz+bxz+cxy$. We can check that this agrees with the formula above: since $$\partial_vA(x,y,z)=
\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 &  \\ 0 & b & 0\\ 0& 0 & c\end{pmatrix}$$
we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}\partial_v&\left(\det A(x,y,z)\right)=\det (A)\,\mathrm{Tr}\left(A^{-1}\partial_vA\right)=\\
&=xyz\,\mathrm{Tr}\left(
\begin{pmatrix} x^{-1} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & y^{-1} & 0\\ 0& 0 & z^{-1}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 &  \\ 0 & b & 0\\ 0& 0 & c\end{pmatrix}
\right)=ayz+bxz+cxy.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I seem to understand this logic. Therefore, I want to check whether it leads to the desired result. To do this, I did some calculations. And stalled at the stage of composition of functions. See my edit, please.

Comment: I.e. I know, how calculate, $adj(A) \partial_x A$,$adj(A) \partial_y A$ or $adj(A) \partial_z A$. But how calculate $adj(A) \partial_v A$ with some linear matrix-vector operations?

Comment: To compute $\partial_vA$, write $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$. Then we should have $\partial_vA=v_1\partial_xA+v_2\partial_yA+v_3\partial_zA$. This is a matrix. Then you multiply by the adjugate matrix of A, and take the trace to get the number you need. Hope this helps!

Comment: Derivative of the matrix $A$ with respect to the vector $v=[x,y,z]$ is easy to calculate ($\partial_v A$). But then it turns out $3 \times 9$-tensor. Multiplication of $3 \times 3$-matrix by $3 \times 9$-tensor is carried out using the Kronecker product. But the result of the product is inside the "trace" function, which only works for square matrices. Look at the @greg answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4511499/656085.

Comment: What operation (or set of operations) is needed for its result to be equivalent to the vector of traces that is presented in @greg answer.

Comment: Why should it be a $3\times 9$ tensor? The derivative of $A$ along $v$ must give us another matrix of the same dimension, it is an element of the tangent space of the set of matrices. To get from greg's answer to mine you start from the vector of traces in his answer and take the scalar product with the components of the vector $v$.

Comment: Let me demonstrate my calculations with a simpler example. Please take a look at Edit №2. I have not yet caught the relationship between your option and my result.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! From your edit it seems to me however that you are calling "derivative with respect to a vector" what is instead the total differential of the function. I will add an example to my answer above.

Comment: Yes, maybe I used not quite the correct name. But I hope my calculations in Mathcad cleared everything up (what I wanted to get). In any case, I'm grateful for the feedback. Looking forward to the example you are talking about.

Comment: yes indeed! anyway, the example is really the most simple you could could come up with.